# negative margin not the same on desktop and mobile

Tags: css

I am trying to get a flag icon to sit half on and half off a particular container. On my desktop it looks perfect and when I use google chrome tools to simulate mobile devices it also looks perfect. But when I look at it on an actual mobile phone the position is incorrect. It is sitting on top of the container.

```
<div className="stats-container">
 <div className="flag">
  <img src={country && country.countryInfo.flag} />
 </div>
</div>

.stats-container {
  padding: 5rem;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 100px rgba(2, 2, 3, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flag img {
  max-width: 70px;
  margin-top: -110px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the country flag icon that you used in the img tag?

Comment: Sure, I have added it to my original question

Comment: Thanks for that. Also can you put some screenshots so the issue will be more clear.

Comment: No problem. I have added an image for desktop view and mobile view

Comment: Maybe there is a @media query working for mobile only?

Comment: The only media query I have is `@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .stats-container .column {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [absolute positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) instead of negative margin? This would display it relative to the nearest ancestor rather than the viewport so shouldn't be affected by screen size. Use can use properties like `top: 10;` to position it then.

Comment: I did actually try that but couldn't get it to stay in the same place. If I used left:50% then it was in the middle on desktop but not on mobile for some reason.

Comment: For example. If I do `left:50%` on desktop it is in the middle but on mobile I have to change it to `left:40%` to get it in the middle

Comment: Ah okay. I think the media query approach would work then. So you could have `left: 50%`  and then below that in the `@media (max-width: 768px)` you could apply the `left: 40%` to the class you are using.

Comment: I have thought of this but it seems a bit clunky and is not guaranteed to work on all devices. Surely there must be a way to always keep this in place without having to do this with a lot of media queries?

Comment: I get what you mean. If the height is working with absolute positioning and it is only the centring that is the issue then there are ways to centre an element rather than relying on only the `left` property. This [Medium article](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/absolute-centering-in-css-ea3a9d0ad72e)  shows how it can be centred using absolute positioning.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong with the absolute positioning from the link you posted. That actually seems to be working.

Comment: Great stuff! Yeah it's a handy one to be aware of.